# Array of static objects of template class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a template class `template<typename T> class TplObject`. I need a static structure kind of array, where indexes are `typename T`. I can do something like this:

```
array.add<Type1>(); // New Object of type TplObject<Type1> was added
TplObject<Type1> obj = array.get<Type1>();
```

Is there such structure, mb in boost? If no, can you suggest how to make it?

Comment: *"where indexes are `typename T`". This doesn't make any sense.  The only reason you could possibly need this is if you expect to create "typename T" instances at runtime.  How would you expect to do this?

Comment: @cdhowie Oh, mb the example is not so good, sorry. I don't want to add this objects in runtime. I want to have an object which is build in compile time and have several instances of class `TplObject` of different template arguments, which can be pulled by type.

Comment: @user14416 Such a container doesn't make much sense, I don't think.  What you are looking for is `std::map<std::type_index, T>` where the `T` depends on the `std::type_index` value.  I'm not sure how you could possibly implement that, except by (ab)using pointers in the data structure.  Perhaps you could demonstrate why you need this, and we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: Do you have a predetermined list of the types you want to instantiate your template with?  Can you put that list in one spot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is an example of doing something like this.  I take a list of types to instantiate a template with, instantiate a template with them, store the instances in a tuple, and provide a type-based lookup `get` method.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

// Metaprogramming boilerplate:
template<typename... Ts> struct type_list {};
template<typename T, typename list, typename=void> struct index_in;
template<typename T, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_in<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,T0>::value>::type>
{
  enum { value = 0 };
};
template<typename T, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_in<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,T0>::value>::type>
{
  enum { value = index_in<T, type_list<Ts...>>::value+1 };
};

// The tuple of instantiations of Factory:
template<template<typename>class Factory, typename... Ts>
struct PolytypeFactory {
  std::tuple< Factory<Ts>... > data;
  template<typename T>
  Factory<T>& get() {
    return std::get< index_in< T, type_list<Ts...> >::value >( data  );
  }
  template<typename T>
  Factory<T> const& get() const {
    return std::get< index_in< T, type_list<Ts...> >::value >( data  );
  }
};

// a test factory, that creates an instance of T from the constant 100.5:
template<typename T> struct maker100_5 { T operator()() const { return T(100.5); } };

// test code, where I create 100.5 as an int, double and char, then print them:
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   PolytypeFactory<maker100_5, int, double, char> factory;
   std::cout << factory.get<int>()() << "," << factory.get<double>()() << "," << factory.get<char>()() << "\n";
}
```

You can defer construction of the contents of `PolytypeFactory` if needed, either by using `boost::optional`, storing pointers-to-`Factory<Ts>` and allowing someone to pass in a `new` version via a method like `get()`, or getting really fancy and doing in-place construction.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index). Combined with `std::shared_ptr`, the following might help you to get started:

```
class typemap
{
    std::map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<void>> map_;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void set(std::shared_ptr<T> obj)
    {
        map_[std::type_index(typeid(T))] = obj;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args)
    {
        this->set(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> get()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(map_[std::type_index(typeid(T))]);
    }
};
```

This example can hold one object of each type, to use it do something like this:

```
typemap m;

// set
m.set( std::make_shared< int >( 42 ) );
m.set( std::make_shared< MyClass >() );
m.set( std::make_shared< std::vector<double> >() );

// or use emplace
m.emplace<int>( 42 );
m.emplace< MyClass >();
m.emplace< std::vector<double> >();

// access
int douglas = *m.get< int >();
m.get< MyClass >()->adams();
m.get< std::vector<double> >()->push_back( 3.141592 );
```